# How programmable is SSAS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, artificial-intelligence, ssas

SSAS - Is it possible to run an iterative cube across different dimensions covering all combinations of permutations of dimensions where a result would suggest the best permutation of dimensions. The roll down of the dimensions remain the same, it's about which dimensions are used...

I don't need the detail, just if it's possible. I'm very good at SSIS, but not really aware of how far SSAS can go.

If you are still reading, then read on. The reason I'm asking is that I have several potentially plausible dimensions relating to a probability 'project' and I would like to find out what the best combination of dimensions to use.

Answer (score 2):

> to run an iterative cube across different dimensions

--> SSAS works differently. You define your cubes and process them.

> cube across different dimensions covering all combinations of permutations of dimensions where a result would suggest the best permutation of dimensions

--> Yes. It can be done using SSAS.

> I have several potentially plausible dimensions relating to a probability 'project' and I would like to find out what the best combination of dimensions to use.

--> In SSAS, we have the opportunity to build the mining models. Your statement sound more like a mining problem that may easily be solved using decision trees or association rule mining model.

Answer (score 1):

> SSAS - Is it possible to run an iterative cube across different dimensions covering all combinations of permutations of dimensions where a result would suggest the best permutation of dimensions. The roll down of the dimensions remain the same, it's about which dimensions are used...

Interesting approach. Yes, it is possible to some extent. SSAS cubes cannot work "interactively" as you wish. You can generate several cubes (generate metadata for it) and then process these cubes. Then you can text each cube and select which fits you the best. However, this is rather unusual way of working with SSAS.

> I don't need the detail, just if it's possible. I'm very good at SSIS, but not really aware of how far SSAS can go

Well, SSIS can help you little on this; it is limited to processing specific dimensions or cubes. I would recommend approaching this task with C# and [AMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/amo/developing-with-analysis-management-objects-amo) or generate SSAS cube with [BIML](https://www.varigence.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the indicators, will look more closely at both mining and AMO